# Testing redux/react with jest erroring on webworker

Tags: global-variables, jestjs

I'm using React-scripts which includes jest to run tests on my redux model (not using much react yet, still building out the data.

I use a webworker to fetch data via an ajax request.

When I run my tests, `Reference Error: Worker is not defined`.

I've tried installing a worker npm library and include that as a global in my test.spec file via
 `import * as global.Worker from "webworker"`, but this doesn't include the webworker in my tests.

I want to avoid having the webworker included in my source, as it isn't needed in the browser, but I would like it for testing, or if I don't test the worker code, at least have my tests not error out because the worker is referenced in the file.

Comment: Have tried `import worker from 'webworker'; global.worker = worker`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with react-scripts, however I would say this:

1) unit tests shouldnt be testing or even running external resources (like webworker) - isolation is key in unit tests

2) redux code, specifically reducers shouldnt rely or execute code relying on external resources or state - they should be [pure](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-redux-needs-reducers-to-be-pure-functions-d438c58ae468#.bpxqsim2j)

you havent provided any code examples so im making a lot of assumptions as to the source of your problem.

one question: you mentioned "redux model" , is this related to something like [redux-orm](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) or just how you call your reducers

In any case as a first step, I would recommend you move the code that calls the web worker (or any external resource) to a separate file and import it in your reducer/model. This way you can [mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html#content) it easily and avoid running it. This allows you to control what response it provides without actually making an outside call.

As a long term suggestion I would recommend you look into something like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/) to do your async work with.

Comment: I completely agree with you, and I'm not calling a webworker in my unit test.
However, my code includes a module which includes a webworker, which is causing this error.

I am already using redux-thunk, though I'm not sure how that get's around the worker. Like I said the worker is never called, the error I'm getting is just saying that it is undefined.

Comment: It still sounds like your test is causing too much code to be executed.  A unit test should only test the one single function.  If another module is running the webworker then your test isnt isolated enough.  That module should be mocked.

Comment: That's fair enough. But somewhere down the line this code is going to have to call a webworker, so not importing the webworker at all or including it somewhere else is going to seem strange... I'll try it though.

Comment: in your tests you have to separate what you test and what you dont. to keep it simple, you should try and never have calls to outside resources from a unit-test. in the same way you shouldnt be calling lodash methods but mock them so they return the value you wish to test with. In your tests you should take for granted that lodash or webworker code, etc. work fine, its your code/logic you should only be concerned about. So in this case, Its not about not calling the webworker from your code, its making sure its NOT actually called when the test is run.

Comment: Thanks, it is definitely not being run, just imported which is causing the issue as it is 'undefined'. So to clarify, the test itself is not failing, but I'm getting an error from the test suite.

Comment: just keep in mind that (imported === executed) when a module is imported, the JS engine will run any JS code it finds so while your code may not be calling an exposed/exported methods from the module, its internal code may still be run if its written that way